# PowerBI Embed Custom Filters Secured?

Tags: powerbi, embed

I am working on a project where we need to embed a Power BI Report in to React application.

We are generating a token using service principal with that we are loading the embed report

We are using a single multitenant database so we have all customer info in the single database.

For some reason I couldn't not use RLS filtering. I want to use custom filters to filter the Embeded Report.

Is the custom filter is secured? If I access the report embed url directly then it is not loading anything, so can I consider generating token and connecting embed report is secured option?

I want to know custom filtered option is secured or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the custom filter is secured?

It's a Javascript API, so it runs in the user's browser, and so it's not secured.

> We are using a single multitenant database so we have all customer info in the single database.

In this scenario either use RLS or create separate Datasets for each tenant.

> **Securing your data**
>
> If you're handling data from multiple customers, there are two main
> approaches to securing your data: [Workspace-based isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-multi-tenancy) and
> [Row-level security-based isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-row-level-security). You can find a detailed comparison
> between them in [service principal profiles and row level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-multi-tenancy#row-level-security).
>
> We recommend using workspace-based isolation with profiles, but if you
> want to use the RLS approach, review the RLS section at the end of
> this article.

[Generate an embed token - Securing your data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/generate-embed-token#securing-your-data)